# Long response time from HDD

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I've faced weird issue with my HDD. I bought it new on august, the model is: `WDC WD10EZEX-00RKKA0`

After 10 minutes it starts to `freezing` every time i make any request to HDD. At first i thought it might be windows issue, but i have mac os installed on other hdd, and there is same thing when im trying to listen music. It simply loading song about 10secods, and red light always enabled(on my case). I tried to run `chkdsk` but no errors were found. Is there something else that i could do before reformatting it?

Comment: Check SMART status. HD Tune will show in under *Health* tab on Windows.

Comment: Smart shows that everything is OK

Comment: Use [Western Digital's diagnostics](http://support.wd.com/product/download.asp?groupid=606&sid=2&lang=en) to check it.

Comment: Try to plug your hd in another SATA slot on the mainboard, with an other SATA data cable.

Comment: Seems like my SATA cable is very old, so i replaced with another one, and it worked well for about 30min.

Comment: @techie007, thanks for link, ill try this out as well.

Comment: This sounds remarkably similar to a problem I just solved:  http://superuser.com/questions/1168116/hdd-takes-a-long-time-to-respond-from-idle-but-smart-tells-me-that-spin-up-time  Basically lots of lag when reading from disk, but SMART says it's a healthy drive.  I turned out I was running the disk in AHCI mode rather than IDE.  You can find these settings in the BIOS.